# Customize drawing in python graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I like to draw a graph using `graph-tool`, where the edge weights are written to the edges.

I can draw a graph, but edge weights strangely annotated:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
g = gt.Graph(directed=True)

import numpy as np
import random
dim = 7 
sparsity = .27

# create adjacency matrix
M1 = np.matrix(random.choices([0,1], weights=[1-sparsity, sparsity], k=dim*dim)).reshape(dim,-1)
M = np.multiply(np.random.randint(1, 10, (dim, dim)), M1)    # element-wise multiplication by M1
np.fill_diagonal(M, 0)  # inplace

adjlist = np.transpose(M.nonzero())

g.add_edge_list(adjlist)
weights = M[M.nonzero()]

#add weights as an edge propertyMap
ew = g.new_edge_property("double")
ew.a = weights 
g.ep['edge_weight'] = ew


gt.graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, vertex_font_size=18, edge_text=ew, edge_font_size=18, output_size=(400, 400),
            output="/home/info/99_deleteme/mygraph.png")
```

This is the graph generated:

[image: Graph]

Where can I find a list of (or even documentation on) all possible `vertex_*` and `edge_*` properties as suggested in https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw ?

Googling only gets me examples like https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/_modules/graph_tool/flow.html?

Comment: Sorry, seems to be my fault... I missed "list of vertex properties" and "list of edge properties" in https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw

Comment: Though I could swear 16 hours ago it had not been there yet ...